# How to calculate constant A in log(Ax+1) using R

Tags: r

I need to calculate the coefficients  in the equation y = 1000*ln(Ax+1)

I fed the table data with x and y and trying to run it through R to calculate the coefficients.

Here is my code.

```
TestModel=read.csv("bdata.csv",header=TRUE)
plot(TestModel$mon,TestModel$count)

TestModel$P = 1000*(log(abs(TestModel$mon+1)))

#TestModel$Q = 1000*(log1p(TestModel$mon))

head(TestModel)

#summary(1000*(log10(1+TestModel$mon)))

output1 = lm(TestModel$count~TestModel$P)

summary(output1)
```

The A value seems to have caculated as 0.47508 , but for this equation, Excel is giving the constant value as 0.1432 which is correct. How can i get that value in R? what am i missing? any help is highly appreciated.

Result is :

```
> head(TestModel)
  count month         P         Q
1   134     1  693.1472 0.6931472
2   252     2 1098.6123 1.0986123
3   357     3 1386.2944 1.3862944
4   453     4 1609.4379 1.6094379
5   540     5 1791.7595 1.7917595
6   620     6 1945.9101 1.9459101

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-41.773 -32.478  -5.554  23.566  74.534 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -269.83135   40.65118  -6.638 5.80e-05 ***
TestModel$P      0.47508    0.02073  22.919 5.64e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 40.25 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9813,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9795 
F-statistic: 525.3 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 5.643e-10
```

Comment: Your code is running the regression y = A0 + A * 1000 * ln(|x+1|) and not y = 1000*ln(Ax+1) . Maybe this is the root of your problem

Comment: Oh, Thank you Luis, Do you know how i can fix this ? I am totally new to this tool,just started learning in last week and not so much help around this topic in internet.

Comment: Hey, Luis  Thank you so much, with littlebit of deep dive, i was able to resolve myself               head(Remodel)

TestModel$R = exp(TestModel$count/1000)

output1 = lm(TestModel$R~TestModel$mon+1)
summary(output1)

Comment: Yup, that looks correct. No problem!